# C# : How to setup Fody Nullguard

Tags: c#, fody

We are trying to use Fody Nullguard in our project but even with a lot of trial (and the same amount of error), we didn't get the automatic null checks running.

We followed the instructions as stated in github repository:

```
PM> Install-Package Fody
PM> Install-Package NullGuard.Fody
```

And setup a simple test project (in many flavors [e.g. .NET core, .net framework, static methods, non static methods...], none of the them worked) like this:

```
static void TheFunc(string o)
{
  Console.WriteLine("I'm alive!");            
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  TheFunc(null);
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

We also added the XML file `FodyWeavers.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Weavers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FodyWeavers.xsd">
  <NullGuard Mode="Implicit" IncludeDebugAssert="false" />
</Weavers>
```

Nevertheless, there is no exception thrown. 
So the question is, if there is any further step necessary to get fody nullguard running?

One thing is that we are using resharper. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: Did you check the msbuild output to verify that fody is running and weaving during compile? There are plenty of Diagnostics with fody, at the very least it shows what weavers have run. Also you may have better luck posting in the NullGuard github issues.

Comment: I think the problem is that your method is not public. By default only public members are modified by NullGuard. You can change this behavior using `NullGuardAttribute`

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I stumbled across it when looking for the answer for the same issue.

Figured out that by default the NullGuard only does the validation on public members (class and method must be public).

You can either make them public or change this behavior by adding the attribute below on top of the file where you do initialization for your application.

```
...
using NullGuard;
[assembly: NullGuard(ValidationFlags.All)]
```